# как выйти из Fragment в Activity при нажатии ImageButton(Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, activity

Не могу разобраться.

Или вместо `Activity` сделать сделать `Fragment`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не вполне ясно что вы хотите сделать. У вас активити, в ней фрагменте, во фрагменте кнопка и вы хотите убрать фрагмент из активити при нажатии на кнопку?

Comment: Все верно, так как вы сказали

Comment: Тогда, если фрагмент у вас через транзакции добавлен и в стэк добавлен, то можно так-то так написать во фрагменте: `activity.supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()`

Comment: ```supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, CreateNoteFragment()).commit()``` вот мой переход с активити в фрагмент. ```activity.supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()``` показывет ошибку

Comment: Какую ошибку? Компиляции или в рантайме падает? И что пишет при ошибке?

Comment: скрин добавил в описание

Comment: Достаточно просто предписание студии выполнить, добавив вопросики перед точками)

Comment: пробовал, ничего не происходит, ни ошибок ни результата

Comment: Попробуйте в транзакции добавлять фрагмент в стек. Как-то так: .addToBackStack("test")

Comment: Сработало. спасибо большое вам за помощь)))